# Flutter deserialization of inherited classes with json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, json-serializable

I have problem trying deserialise inherited class with json_serializable package in Dart/Flutter. Here is the code example:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Document  {
  String id = UniqueKey().toString();
  String name='';
  List<Component> components=[];   //list of Components
  Document({required this.components}):super();
  Document.empty();

  factory Document.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>_$DocumentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DocumentToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Component {   //Component Base Class
  String id = UniqueKey().toString();
  String name='';

  Component();

  factory Component.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>_$ComponentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ComponentToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class TextComponent extends Component{   //inherited from Component
  String text='';
  TextComponent():super();
  TextComponent.text({required this.text}):super();

  factory TextComponent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>_$TextComponentFromJson(json);
  @override Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TextComponentToJson(this);

}
```

And here is the test:

```
void main() {

  //creating json from object
  Document d = Document(components:[TextComponent.text(text: 'text')] );
  print(d.components[0].runtimeType); //-type is : TextComponent
  var json = d.toJson();

  //create object from json
  var newDoc = Document.fromJson(json);
  print(newDoc.components[0].runtimeType);  //-type is : Component which is the base class

}
```

After deserialising the inherited class is downcasted to base class, but i need the inherited class.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found this package which does everything:
https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mappable#custom-mappers